# Игра морской бой, связать GUI и логику

Tags: java, многопоточность, gui

Привет народ. Пишу морской бой, с графикой на JavaFX. Есть главный игровой цикл в котором игрок и компьютер стреляют, ну и собственно вся логика происходит. Пока все было в консольном виде, проблем не было и цикл просто не шел дальше, пока пользователь не введет в консоль координаты. Но вот пришло время присоединять GUI и тут возникла проблема. Поле нарисовано на канвасе и при клике считываются координаты. Но теперь главный вопрос: как сделать так, чтоб цикл ждал, пока пользователь кликнул по канвасу(полю)? Если это важно, то графика в FXML написана, а приложение по принципу MVC.
Слышал что-то о ивентах и засыпании/просыпании потоков, но ничего конкретного.

Answer (score 1):

Привет!
Пошагово опишу как я вижу решение целиком, цикла то не вижу)
1. Создать абстрактный класс. Поля: x, y позиции и обнаружение (boolean).  Абстрактный метод на внешний вид: `public abstract Node appearance();`
2. Создать 2 субкласса(корабль и промах) (extends). Пример:

```
    public class Ship extends АбстрактныйКласс{
private Rectangle appearance;
public Ship (int x, int y) {
    super(x,y);
    appearance = new Rectangle(20,20,Color.GRAY);
}

@Override
public void move(Game gamer) {
    gamer.setxPos(getxPos());
    gamer.setyPos(getyPos());
}@Override
public Node appearance() {

    return appearance;
}

@Override
public void setDetected(boolean detected){
    super.setDetected(detected);
    if(detected){
        appearance.setFill(Color.BLACK);
    }else{
        appearance.setFill(Color.GRAY);
    }
}
```

3. Класс самой игры с get и set позиций.
4. Ну и соответственно main класс extends Application

```
   @Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        GridPane root = new GridPane();...
```

с методом обработки массива задающего положение караблей.
При обрисовке поля боя setDetected установить в false, что бы все как у меня в  примере было серым.
5. Класс на нажатие левой кнопки мыши на определенных координатах, который меняет внешний вид обнаруженного поля.

ну как, то так. Какие то моменты упустил, обрисовал концепцию

если все таки Canvas

```
    Canvas pole = new Canvas(400, 400);

        root.setCenter(pole);
        pole.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, 
                        new Move(pole.getGraphicsContext2D()));

     public class Move implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {
GraphicsContext teg;        
double X;           
double Y;           


public Move(GraphicsContext t) {
    teg = t;
}

@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent hendelsen) {

    double x = hendelsen.getX();
    double y = hendelsen.getY();
```

получаем координаты, смотрим в массив  и описываем что делать, т.е. менять внешний вид, или рисовать чего нибудь.